# File creation with random content, size and name

Tags: linux, shell, file

I need to create files with random content, size and names as fast as possible.

I have tried using the code below but they are  extremely slow (10MBps)

The server is a 64 proc, 256GB of ram and NVMes in PCIe-Gen4 slots.
With FIO I can hit 4.6GBps for a mix of sequential (70%) random workload (30%)

```
seq -w 1 100 | xargs -n1 -I% sh -c 'dd if=/dev/urandom of=$(mktemp XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Z-$z-I$i) bs=$(python -S -c "import random; print random.randrange(1,100)") count=$((RANDOM + 1024 ))'


for z in {1..1000000}; do
   for i in {1..10000}; do
        dd if=/dev/urandom of=$(mktemp XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Z-$z-I$i) bs=$(python -S -c "import random; print random.randrange(1,100)") count=$((RANDOM + 1024 ))  >/dev/null 2>&1
    done 
done
```

BTW I am not proficient in Linux and I would appreciate some detail and explanation with your suggestions
Thanks!

Comment: Generating random numbers is slow. You can run `haveged`, it's known to speed things up a bit. You are creating `100000000000` files with a mean of `100 / 2 *  (32768 + 1024) / 2 = 844800` random bytes. That's a lot of random bytes. It's going to take a lot of time. And a lot of cpu time. (btw. that python is simpler with just `$((RANDOM % 100))`).

Comment: The random block size is probably a bad idea; if the block size is small or not a multiple of the hardware / kernel block size, it will slow down your I/O considerably.  I'd change it to write blocks of a large fixed size and only vary the count.

Comment: Also, as it stands you are only using 1 of your 64 CPUs.  You might want to look into using something like GNU `parallel` to get many of these jobs to run simultaneously.

Comment: How would you use parallel? can you modify my example? I tried dd if=/dev/urandom of=$(mktemp XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Z-$z-I$i) bs=$(python -S -c "import random; print random.randrange(1,100)") count=$((RANDOM + 1024 ))  | parallel -J60 and did not make a difference

Comment: @user453191 Please be careful when quoting `fio` numbers when you are not giving your full fio command line. A common fio mistake is to not bypass (or account for) kernel caching at which point you may be testing the speed of dumping things into and out of RAM rather than the speed of getting things to and from disk.

Comment: my problem is not with FIO but with how slow the process of creating files with random content in Linux and was hoping I could get help improving my code.